# Rails Drop-down search database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-7, stimulusjs

I have a Model Location.
Each location has a name.

A user is filling out a form in which they must choose a location name.

The drop-down would be too long to be practical.

I'd like it such that I can have them type a few characters then a few suggested name appears allowing them to select one.

I usually use rails select helpers but this time the list is too long to be practical.

I'm using rails 7 with import maps.

How would I implement this?

Comment: I think you can implement this https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Comment: @Mehmood this would require the entire list to be loaded in the front end would it not?

Comment: You could test it. I have implemented this in the past but I don’t remember entire list loading.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `datalist`. This will create a drop-down that updates matching values while typing.

```
<%= f.text_field :location, list: 'location-list', autocomplete: 'off' %>
<datalist id="location-list">
  <% for location in Location.select(:location_name) %>
    <option><%= location %></option>
  <% end %>
</datalist>
```

Comment: Thank you. I will test later. But would this allow  items not in the list to be entered?

Comment: Oh yes it would...

Comment: Not quite the solution I had in mind.